# Run 'export' command Over SSH

Tags: bash, ssh

When I run the following from my `bash` shell:

```
bash -c '(export abc=123 && echo $abc)'
```

The output is "123".  But when I run it over `ssh`:

```
ssh remote-host "bash -c '(export abc=123 && echo $abc)'"
```

There is no output.  Why is this?  Is there a way around this?  That is, is there a way to set an environment variable for a command I run over `ssh`?

Note: When I replace `echo $abc` with something standard like `echo $USER` the `ssh` command prints out the username on the remote machine as expected since it is already set.

I am running RHEL 5 Linux with OpenSSH 4.3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is because when using

```
ssh remote-host "bash -c '(export abc=123 && echo $abc)'"
```

the variable gets expanded by the *local* shell (as it is the case with `$USER`) before `ssh` executes. Escape the `$` by using `\$` and it should do fine

```
ssh remote-host "bash -c '(export abc=123 && echo \$abc)'"
```

On a side note:

- You don't need to export just for this.
- You don't need to wrap it in ()

Like so:

```
ssh remote-host "bash -c 'abc=123 && echo \$abc'"
```

Heck, you can even leave out the `bash -c ...` stuff, as the ssh manpage states:

> If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.

But these may be specific to your task ;)

Comment: excellent, thanks!  there's much more to what i'm doing, so i will have to use 'bash -c' and 'export', but this should definitely solve it.