# Bash: using EXPORT inside SSH command

Tags: bash, ssh

When executing this command:

```
user@local:~ >ssh user@remote " export myvar=myvalue ; echo myvar=$myvar ; "
```

I get output:

```
myvar=
```

When running directly on remote machine, I get the expected result:

```
user@remote:~ > export myvar=myvalue ; echo myvar=$myvar ;
```

Output:

```
myvar=myvalue
```

So how to set a variable inside ssh command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run 'export' command Over SSH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663615/run-export-command-over-ssh)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because you're using double quotes, so the variable is being expanded on your *local* machine *before* ssh is even invoked. Use single quotes:

```
ssh user@remote 'export myvar=myvalue ; echo myvar=$myvar'
```

Comment: you are misleading the guy! it doesn't work, the $myvar prints the local value

Comment: @HeshamYassin, you are incorrect. Try this: `export x=local; echo $x; ssh user@remote 'export x=remote; echo $x'; echo $x`