# Where can I store variables and values for current Unix user so that I can use them in SSH and scripts?

Tags: bash, variables, unix, scripting

I have some variables I use quite frequently to configure and tweak my Ubuntu LAMP server stack but I'm getting tired of having to copy and paste the **export** command into my SSH window to register the variable and its value.

Essentially I would like to keep my variables and their values in a file inside the user profiles home directory so when I type a command into a SSH window or execute a bash script the variables can be easily used. I don't want to set any system-wide variables as some of these variables are for setting passwords etc.

What's the easiest way of doing this?

**UPDATE 1**

So essentially I could store the variables and values in a file and then each time I login into a SSH session I call this file up once to setup the variables?

```
cat <<"EOF" >> ~/my_variables
export foo='bar'
export hello="world"
EOF
```

```
ssh root@example.com 
$ source ~/my_variables
$ echo "$foo"
$ bar
```

and then to call the variable from within a script I place `source ~/my_variables` at the top of the script?

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/my_variables
echo "$hello"
```

Comment: export var during your initial ssh session: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052607/bash-using-export-inside-ssh-command/19052798

Answer (score 0):

Just add your `export` commands to a file and then run `source <the-file>` (or `. <the-file>` for non-bash shells) in your SSH session.